# Simple way to continuously look up in a very busy table without blocking it

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that receives thousands of inserts per minute and it's important that the inserts are done extremely quickly as it would otherwise cause performance problems elsewhere in my application. That's why this table does not contain any indexes at all. This works out well and the insert performance is satisfactory.

However, I would also like to look up in this table very often, like every second with complex queries. I can't do it on the table as it is, because without indexes it would be performing way too slow.

So I would like to continuously move the data from this table to another table that does contain indexes. However, let's say I move it with a simple sql script every minute, I am afraid I risk blocking inserts to the table while I'm moving records (insert + delete in transaction) and that would be a problem for the performance of my application.

So what would be a smart (but/and simple) way to accomplish this?

Here are my best ideas so far:

**1. Use SQL Server Service Broker**

I put a trigger on the table and add new items to the service broker which I think should be asynchronous and not cause performance problems. Then I need another job to read from the queue. I haven't done this before and I'm not sure how good this solution is.

**2. Use "Replication"**

I do not like this solution because of the complex setup of replication so I mention it here to say that I would be happy to not receive suggestions on this.

**3. Just do it**

Maybe I'm overthinking it. Should I run this every minute?

```
BEGIN Transaction
-- Insert all rows in other table
-- Delete all rows from table
END Transaction
```

Note, the target table will also be quite busy, so perhaps this job would wait in queue for heavy queries to complete.

Looking forward to hearing your suggestions on how to approach this challenge.

Comment: You will need to do load testing against the threshold after which the number of inserts per second becomes unacceptable  before going for so many solutions

Comment: Let's say for the sake of this question, that I expect it will go up by 100% per year and it starts becoming a problem in 18 months.

Comment: @NielsBrinch I was wondering what solution did you take? I'm considering activating the Service Broker for a very busy server with hundreds of databases, so I was wondering if you enabled the broker and what performances you got?

Comment: I remember using In-Memory tables for this kind of work. I used In-Memory tables for acquiring rows (super-fast) and the put them in disk-based tables later (slower). I remember being [inspired by this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9DnjQqE0Gc). Hekaton = In-Memory OLTP tables now (in SQL 2016+).

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. For sure replication on a cluster with read on secondary nodes is probably the most clean solution, but if you cannot put that infrastructure in place or cannot afford the Entreprise license, then I would go with the broker.
You would need to test both of your solution but my guess is that the "Just do it" solution will encounter many deadlocks and lead to slowness problems.
I know this is an old question so I was wondering what solution did you choose in the end?
My vote goes to the Broker.
Since your read queries are complex, you could do a sort-of "big data" architecture where the broker doesn't simply copies data to another table but also pre-calculates some of the stuff you need in your heavy read queries. For example, if you need to get the average or sum of some data for a period of date, you could pre-calculate those with the broker so that your read queries are easier to run. That way your other queries would also be lighter on the system.

Comment: Thank you for re-awakening this question. That gives me the pleasure of describing the answer I chose. I made sure the time was synchronized for both web and db server. Then every even and odd minute number I switched between two input tables. Whenever the time changed, I knew one table would have data from one minute and not be used, so I could take everything and put it in the indexed table used for lookups. One minute was more than enough time to move the data.

Comment: That's a pretty clever solution! I'll keep that in mind, it might serve me :-)